# Can not resolve http://localhost:8080/ on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, localhost

I'm trying to use a local server on my mac, but it seems to ignore the localhost settings in the /etc/hosts file. Found several pages where solution was to do a reinstall, and put localhost to the first place of /etc/hosts etc... I believe these are more than needed.

Does anybody still have the same problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found that behind proxy by the default only the *.local is excluded, so just need to add localhost and 127.0.0.1 to avoid DNS resolution on the local machine. Put

```
*.local, localhost, 127.0.0.1
```

into the following setting dialog:

> System Preferences/Network/Advanced/Proxies/Bypass proxy settings for
>   these Hosts & Domains

Comment: Thanks Chad for the feedback, I mark it as answered based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what server you're trying to get going and maybe i'm not understanding the question. Lion comes with the localhost alias in /etc/hosts by default and it seems unlikely that that alias should stop working. Can you ping localhost? Can you access the server through 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Thanks for that, ping is fine. Found that proxy settings did not exclude localhost, only *.local by default.

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee it's your hosts file. I did all of this and have been messing around with the proxy settings and hosts - and no surprise, I screwed things up. This is what I did:
Put you osx proxy settings back to default (*.local, 169.254/16) and leave passive checked. Nothing else is checked. 
Make sure your hosts file has the right header section - the first few lines. If you don't know what this is, you never touched it so don't worry. Either way, check it at /etc/hosts. 
You can do a quick search for the default osx hosts file (sorry, this site is too strict for me to paste)
Don't forget to flush your osx dns! 
dscacheutil -flushcache on 10.7 +.
You should be good. For me, I need to stop messing around so much with things like this because it is easy to mess up and then a pain to troubleshoot. 
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your info is valuable to get a grasp on how it works.